# Powershell Remote WSMan trustedhost no effect

Tags: powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

My intent is to enable powerShell remote for servers that are located in a specific AD OU and allow only certain computers to connect to them. I managed to accomplish the first part using Group Policy by following the link bellow but adding hostnames to the TrustedHosts in WSMan configuration has no effect. I always can connect from any hosts no matter what value I enter.

https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-enable-powershell-remoting-via-group-policy/

Comment: you should understand winrm and its configuration. Trusted host list is for the local machine, it will get effected only to the local system. By adding serverA to trusted list of ServerB will enable connectivity from ServerB to A without any problem, but any other Server can still connect to ServerA.

Comment: I think I understand that much. What I don't understand is why I am able to connect to server B from server C if I only added server A to the trustedhosts lists of server B.

Answer (score 1):

Trusted hosts list is for out going connections, not for incoming connections.
If you add ServerA as a Trusted host in ServerB. Winrm trusts ServerA and connection from ServerB to ServerA is possible. The trusted hosts list is applicable for all winrm connections from ServerB, ServerA is not at all aware of this.

Once again, Trusted hosts list is for out going connections, not for incoming connections.

Comment: Humm so if I don't want any other computers in the domain to connect to server B other than server A I cannot specify it in the truestedhosts list of server B? How can I do it then?